# activerecord - Time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This has got to be extremely simple but I'm banging my head against the wall trying to find an answer.  I want to find the last updated record using the instance method shown below.

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments, :dependent => :destroy

  def get_last_assignment_date 
    @last_date = self.assignments.select("date_assigned").last
    @last_day = @last_date.wday
  end
```

Where my assignments model looks like this:

```
create_table "assignments", :force => true do |t|
t.date     "date_assigned"
<snip>
```

But Rails returns the following error for get_last_assignment_date:

```
undefined method `wday' for #<Assignment date_assigned: "2012-08-30">
```

I need to convert the value returned by active record to a Time format that Ruby can handle but I can't figure out how to do it and it seems to be so easy that no one has even bothered to write how to do it.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
self.assignments.select("date_assigned").last
```

returns an `Assigment` object, not a `Time` object.

So, instead of:

```
@last_day = @last_date.wday
```

you have to do:

```
@last_day = @last_date.date_assigned.wday
```

---

You may be aware of this, but just in case: `select("date_assigned").last` doesn't give you the latest date. You have to use `order`:

```
self.assignments.order(:date_assigned).last
```

Of course if the most recently created object is also the one with the latest `date_assigned` then it doesn't matter.